# File upload for Netty 4.x example

Tags: file-upload, netty, httpserver

How make upload http file server with Netty 4.x ? For 3.x is an example, for 4.x example only for serving static file.

Answer (score 1):

I use netty-all:4.1.32.Final do upload file server

```java
    // Post request
    private void formParams(HttpServerRequest request, ByteBuf content, Map<String, String> formParams, Map<String, MemoryFileUpload> fileParams) {
        if (content != null) {
            // POST Params
            FullHttpRequest dhr = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(request.version(), request.method(), request.uri(), content, request.requestHeaders(), EmptyHttpHeaders.INSTANCE);
            HttpPostRequestDecoder postDecoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(new DefaultHttpDataFactory(false), dhr);
            List<InterfaceHttpData> postData = postDecoder.getBodyHttpDatas();
            for (InterfaceHttpData data : postData) {
                // General Post Content
                if (data.getHttpDataType() == InterfaceHttpData.HttpDataType.Attribute) {
                    MemoryAttribute attribute = (MemoryAttribute) data;
                    formParams.put(attribute.getName(), attribute.getValue());
                }
                // Upload
                else if (data.getHttpDataType() == InterfaceHttpData.HttpDataType.FileUpload) {
                    MemoryFileUpload fileUpload = (MemoryFileUpload) data;
                    fileParams.put(fileUpload.getName(), fileUpload);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpPostRequestDecoder is not ported to 4.0.0.x yet. So there is no support for it atm. It's on the to-do-list.